# JFrog Artifactory Plugin - Discard old builds within Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: plugins, build, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Trying to discard old builds using JFrog artifactory plugin for Jenkins, using:

```
    rtBuildInfo(
        buildName: "test-build",
        buildNumber: "3",
        maxBuilds: 2,
        deleteBuildArtifacts: false,
        asyncBuildRetention: false
    )
    rtCreateDockerBuild(
        serverId: "my-server",
        sourceRepo: "my-repo",
        kanikoImageFile: "image-file",
        buildName: "test-build",
        buildNumber: "3"
    )
    rtPublishBuildInfo(
        serverId: "my-server",
        buildName: "test-build",
        buildNumber: "3"
    )
```

1. rtBuildInfo:
   1.a Should be invoked before create Build? Before publish build, doesn't metter?
   1.b Seems ***buildNumber*** is manadatory, because if missing, no retention is done, and no builds are removed (Unlike the CLI ***jf rt bdi*** command, that doesn't require the buildNumber - makes sense. Why is it mandatory in rtBuildInfo?
2. What's the meaning of 'asyncBuildRetention'? What's the default value?
3. Is there a way to run JFrog CLI in kaniko container running on a Jenkins that uses the artifactory plugin in K8S env?
4. Where detailed docs with parameter description and default values for the artifactory plugin declarative functions?https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#rtbuildinfo-create-build-info is missing this info.
5. How can JFrog log level be increased (e.g. set to DEBUG) when using the declarative functions from jenkins plugin?