# JFrog CLI - Fail to delete a build when build name is with '/'

Tags: build, jfrog-cli

Trying to delete a build with name including "%2f" chars. The "%2f" is encoded to / so API fails with error message that build is missing (404).
How can I force JFrog to avoid encoding the %2f in the build name?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/delete-builds) API. The build name is passed in the JSON so it won't be encoded.

```
curl -uadmin -XPOST https://<$MY_JFROG>/artifactory/api/build/delete -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
    "buildName": "buil%2fd",
    "buildNumbers": ["1"],
    "deleteArtifacts": false,
    "deleteAll": false
}'
```

Comment: Another JFrog Artifcatory question that maybe you can check:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084196/jfrog-artifactory-plugin-discard-old-builds-within-jenkins-pipeline ? thanks

Comment: The curl command indeed worked out! thanks @Hanan!